# Combining two lists randomly

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm trying to combine these two lists into one dictionary. However, on the second for loop it just keeps going through that and not going back to the first. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

```
import random
chores = ['dishes','bathroom','vacuum','walk dog']
assign = {}
emails = ['a','b','c','d']

x=0
while x < 4:
    for i in chores:
        randomChore = random.choice(chores)
        chores.remove(randomChore)
    
        for key in emails: 
            assign[key] = randomChore
            x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, the `for key in emails:`  part needed to be removed. it would choose the random chore then loop through, adding the emails without choosing another random chore.

here is the working code.

```py
import random
chores = ['dishes','bathroom','vacuum','walk dog']
assign = {}
emails = ['a','b','c','d']

x = 0
for i in range(0, len(chores)):
    randomChore = random.choice(chores)
    chores.remove(randomChore)

    assign[emails[x]] = randomChore
    x = x + 1
    
print(assign)
```

Comment: This one works too (+1) not sure who downvoted, but you can make a little compact

Comment: I suggest you try this with only three items in each list. And also explain why you need the outside `while` loop?

Comment: good idea to simplify the code, I was trying to point out where they got it wrong. I will edit it

Comment: What you are doing wrong is deleting items from the list you are iterating over. That's never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you!! This was so simple and I was stuck on it for so long.

Comment: This response made the most sense and wasn't too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `random.shuffle`, and it works like this

```
import random

chores = ['dishes','bathroom','vacuum','walk dog']
assign = {}
emails = ['a','b','c','d']

random.shuffle(chores)
res = {key:val for key,val in zip(emails,chores)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you don't need the useless inner and while loop an iterate over keys instead:

```
import random
chores = ['dishes','bathroom','vacuum','walk dog']
assign = {}
emails = ['a','b','c','d']


for i in emails:
  randomChore = random.choice(chores)
  chores.remove(randomChore)
  assign[i] = randomChore

print(assign)
```

Comment: Why the downvote on this answer? This works properly.

Comment: ikr mine got downvote too.... confusion. ill upvote, it works

Comment: Don't know if this is worth a downvote, but it's pretty bad that you needed to destroy the input chores in order to do this. Also removing items in an array in a loop is inefficient — you have essentially made a simple thing require O(n²) complexity. It makes a lot more sense to just shuffle the array.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if you have two for loops it will keep iterating over the second one and then go back to the first?